# Postgresql regular expression matching function: regexp_matches

Tags: sql, arrays, regex, postgresql

Given a string I want to extract all expression matching a regexp (e.g. email) as an array. Here is my actual code, using **PostgreSQL 9.4** :

```
select regexp_matches('user1@gml.com lorem ipsum user2@yho.com',
                      '([a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4})',
                      'g')
```

The output is 2 records:

```
 regexp_matches  
 -----------------
 {user1@gml.com}
 {user2@yho.com}
 (2 rows)
```

What I want is to have all the matches in one array e.g.:

```
regexp_matches  
-----------------
{user1@gml.com, user2@yho.com}
(1 row)
```

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can `unnest` each result array, then `array_agg` the lot of them together.

It's a bit ugly:

```
select array_agg(x)
from (
    select unnest(
       regexp_matches('user1@gml.com lorem ipsum user2@yho.com',
                      '([a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4})',
                      'g')
    )
) a(x);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer @CraigRinger, I will use your suggestion and create a function.